# How is Activity Monitor Pulling processes specific memory information?

Tags: sql-server-2012, activity-monitor

How is SQL Server Management Studio's Activity Monitor pulling the following memory by processes information?

The screen I am talking about is...
Log into the database, right click on the server in the tree on the left and select activity monitor. 
Expand out processes. 
The Memory Use column - where is it coming? Is there an internal database table that it is pulling from?

I ask because I am trying to figure what all goes into this metric so I can determine if one of the processes is growing without bound or growing as expected due to design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Memory Use column - where is it coming?

It corresponds to `memory_usage` column in `sys.dm_exec_sessions`.

As a friendly note, I would suggest **not to** use Activity Monitor.

Use  Adam Machanic‘s free procedure, [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com) (uses DMVs). You can even [log into a table](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/) for post analysis.

Kendra Little talks about [Activity monitor limitations](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/why-i-dont-use-sql-server-activity-monitor/) :

- It groups wait types
- Leaves out wait types
- Dont leave it open ... else it will boil down your server :-)